# Start a powershell script at the end of Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows, powershell, installation

I have a custom ISO image and I would like at the end of its installation, before logging in to the user, to run my PowerShell script.

I've seen some custom ISOs that do this. How is it done?

Comment: What did you use to create your custom image, and what are you using to install it? For example, if you were using MDT, you could simply add a task of type "Run Command Line"

Comment: Currently I install Windows on one computer, after that I remove the hard drive, put it on another computer and do the install.wim with the Gimagex program. After that I create a flash drive with boot from Rufus with the official Windows 10 Iso, delete the "install.esd" from the bootable flash drive and paste what I did with the Gimagex program

Answer (score 1):

Before capturing your WIM image, you can set up a script to run on first boot in a few different ways. There's a lot of detail and examples here to read: [Add a custom script to Windows setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-script-to-windows-setup?view=windows-11#:%7E:text=cmd%20file%20in%20the%20%25WINDIR,%5CPanther%5CUnattendGC%5CSetupact.). I would recommend one of these options:

1. **Simple CMD** Create a script here: `%WINDIR%\Setup\Scripts\SetupComplete.cmd`. This script runs with local system permissions and starts immediately after the user sees the desktop.
2. **More Complex** Create an `Unattend.xml` file with the [FirstLogonCommands\SynchronousCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands) setting to run after the Out of Box Experience (OOBE) but before the user sees the desktop.
3. **Powershell** Create a scheduled task set to run once at startup, then copy your script to `C:\Windows\Tasks\MyScript.ps1`:

```
# schedule to run at next startup
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

# first, it runs your script
$action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-F "C:\Windows\Tasks\MyScript.ps1"'
# then it removes this task when done so it doesn't run again
$action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-C Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Confirm:$false'

# run as local admin
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

# finally, register everything and you're done!
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'MyTask' -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Description 'My task to run after first startup' -ErrorAction Stop
```

---

Capture wim after doing one of the above, and you should be set.

Comment: I have an Autounattend.xml that I made from the website https://www.windowsafg.com/ and it works great.

I would like to start powershell script with it. But I have no idea where I can put the script. I've already tried to put it in the C:\ directory before generating the .wim but without success.

Would it be possible for me to put on my pendrive with the windows image that I use to format? 

My Autounattend.xml
https://anotepad.com/note/read/ci7ccw5k

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an unattend.xml script, you must run c:\windows\system32\sysprep /generalize /oobe /unattend:autounattend.xml /shutdown, and before the shutdown, generate the wim image booting from winPE or similar tool.

This way your wim image is ready to deploy in any other machine, and the script you selected inside the autounattend.xml will run on boot.